# How to make logicproof do page break automatically?

Tags: page-breaking, logicproof

A minimal working sample is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{logicproof}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{logicproof}{0}
    statement & justification \\
    \forall x \, P(x) & premise \\
    \forall x \, Q(x) & $\forall x \, \mathrm{i}$ 3--5\\
    statement & justification \\
    \forall x \, P(x) & premise \\
    \forall x \, Q(x) & $\forall x \, \mathrm{i}$ 3--5\\
    statement & justification \\
    \forall x \, P(x) & premise \\
    \forall x \, Q(x) & $\forall x \, \mathrm{i}$ 3--5\\
    statement & justification \\
    \forall x \, P(x) & premise \\
    \forall x \, Q(x) & $\forall x \, \mathrm{i}$ 3--5\\
    statement & justification \\
    \forall x \, P(x) & premise \\
    \forall x \, Q(x) & $\forall x \, \mathrm{i}$ 3--5\\
    statement & justification \\
    \forall x \, P(x) & premise \\
    \forall x \, Q(x) & $\forall x \, \mathrm{i}$ 3--5\\
    statement & justification \\
    \forall x \, P(x) & premise \\
    \forall x \, Q(x) & $\forall x \, \mathrm{i}$ 3--5\\
    statement & justification \\
    \forall x \, P(x) & premise \\
    \forall x \, Q(x) & $\forall x \, \mathrm{i}$ 3--5\\
    statement & justification \\
    \forall x \, P(x) & premise \\
    \forall x \, Q(x) & $\forall x \, \mathrm{i}$ 3--5\\
    statement & justification \\
    \forall x \, P(x) & premise \\
    \forall x \, Q(x) & $\forall x \, \mathrm{i}$ 3--5\\
    statement & justification \\
    \forall x \, P(x) & premise \\
    \forall x \, Q(x) & $\forall x \, \mathrm{i}$ 3--5\\
    statement & justification \\
    \forall x \, P(x) & premise \\
    \forall x \, Q(x) & $\forall x \, \mathrm{i}$ 3--5
\end{logicproof}
\end{document}
```

**QUESTION:** *The logicproof as above is so long that can't do page break. Is there any way to make all logicproofs do page break automatically?*

Answer (score 1):

Nested proof are not really supported by the following patch.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{logicproof}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\let\longlogicproof\logicproof
\let\endlonglogicproof\endlogicproof
\patchcmd{\longlogicproof}
  {\center\expandafter\tabular}
  {\expandafter\longtable}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\endlonglogicproof}
  {\endcenter}
  {}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\endlonglogicproof}
  {\endtabular}
  {\endlongtable}
  {}{}
\setcounter{LTchunksize}{1000}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{longlogicproof}{0}
    statement & justification \\
    \forall x \, P(x) & premise \\
    \forall x \, Q(x) & $\forall x \, \mathrm{i}$ 3--5\\
    statement & justification \\
    \forall x \, P(x) & premise \\
    \forall x \, Q(x) & $\forall x \, \mathrm{i}$ 3--5\\
    statement & justification \\
    \forall x \, P(x) & premise \\
    \forall x \, Q(x) & $\forall x \, \mathrm{i}$ 3--5\\
    statement & justification \\
    \forall x \, P(x) & premise \\
    \forall x \, Q(x) & $\forall x \, \mathrm{i}$ 3--5\\
    statement & justification \\
    \forall x \, P(x) & premise \\
    \forall x \, Q(x) & $\forall x \, \mathrm{i}$ 3--5\\
    statement & justification \\
    \forall x \, P(x) & premise \\
    \forall x \, Q(x) & $\forall x \, \mathrm{i}$ 3--5\\
    statement & justification \\
    \forall x \, P(x) & premise \\
    x\forall x \, Q(x) & $\forall x \, \mathrm{i}$ 3--5\\
    statement & justification \\
    \forall x \, P(x) & premise \\
    \forall x \, Q(x) & $\forall x \, \mathrm{i}$ 3--5\\
    statement & justification \\
    \forall x \, P(x) & premise \\
    \forall x \, Q(x) & $\forall x \, \mathrm{i}$ 3--5\\
    statement & justification \\
    \forall x \, P(x) & premise \\
    \forall x \, Q(x) & $\forall x \, \mathrm{i}$ 3--5\\
    statement & justification \\
    \forall x \, P(x) & premise \\
    \forall x \, Q(x) & $\forall x \, \mathrm{i}$ 3--5\\
    statement & justification \\
    \forall x \, P(x) & premise \\
    \forall x \, Q(x) & $\forall x \, \mathrm{i}$ 3--5
\end{longlogicproof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So if there are many nested proofs, this method doesn't work well.

Comment: @Kuttens If you’re able to keep nested proofs in their own page, it should work. Splitting nested proofs across pages needs a complete reworking of the package.